# Has Naruto ever killed anyone?

Tags: naruto

Just a curious thought I had recently. Naruto has been in an awful lot of fights but I can't recall if he ever actually killed another person.

Comment: I doubt it. Just like Fairy Tail and other similar series it's unlikely that the main hero would kill anyone, but an interesting thought never the less.

Comment: Naruto did kill Kakuzu and Pain ***however*** he did not kill any "human beings".

Comment: I just found something that I suspect might confirm your question [here](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080925195252AAqkGdX)

Comment: Intentionally no, Naruto never wanted to kill except for those enemies worth killing for. But, I bet he maimed innocent people unconsciously especially when he reluctantly controlled by the Cubi inside him.

Comment: He killed the girl with rinnegan in Blood Prison movie

Comment: I think the whole killing thing is moved out of focus because it is a series for children. Would be very lackluster to fight in multiple wars and become hokage ("warchief" as in symbol of strength and pinnacle of power for a village) without killing. Very contradictory to the whole "this world is war-torn and mercyless" depiction

Answer (score 32):

Technically speaking, Naruto never landed the killing blow on anyone.

- Haku, even though beaten by Naruto, jumped in front of Kakashi's Raikiri.
- Kakuzu, hit directly by the Rasenshuriken, survived, and later killed by Kakashi.
- Pain's bodies were already dead. Nagato, the living puppeteer, sacrificed himself after hearing Naruto's resolve, with the Rinne Tensei, and revived all the people of the village.

You could say that Naruto was a major cause in all of these people's death, but he did not directly kill any of them.

Comment: 'Cold blooded kakashi', name suits him well :)

Comment: He killed multiple white zetsus though ;)

Comment: @SahanDeSilva he made them into tree, so not really dead

Comment: @AnkitSharma I have challenged this claim: [Do zetsu clones die when they converts into trees?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/64093/do-zetsu-clones-die-when-they-converts-into-trees)

Comment: Naruto technically killed Kakuzu, though. Even if Kakashi didn't kill Kakuzu's final heart, Naruto's Rasenshuriken damaged the final heart to the brink of failure, and it caused extensive and irreversible damage to all of his cells. Even if his final heart somehow survived, he wouldn't have lived much longer, as the rest of his organ systems have been completely obliterated by countless microscopic wind blades.

Answer (score 16):

There is someone I know. [Yūra](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Y%C5%ABra) was defeated and killed by Naruto's [Big Ball Rasengan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Ball_Rasengan). His corpse was later devoured by Zetsu.

Comment: It can be argued that he was a sacrifice for the jutsu similar to the Reanimation Jutsu.

Comment: Yes, but it is explicitly stated in the wiki that Yūra was defeated and killed by Naruto.

Comment: Yet the body used in the jutsu already died, so it was a living corpse.

Comment: A 'living sacrifice' means that Naruto actually killed him but under Memory-Concealing Manipulative Sand Technique of Sasori and Shapeshifting Technique from Pain. It is not the technique from the two (Sasori and Pain) that cause his death.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this thread is old, but I just want to point out that Naruto did kill Aoi Rokusho with the Rasengan. Aoi Rokusho is a rogue ninja who ran away from the Leaf Village with the sacred Thunder Sword that belonged to the 2nd Hokage. Naruto attacked the Thunder Sword that Aoi sensei was using and that sent Aoi sensei plummeting down the cliff, which according to Aoi himself, is a fatal fall. This was during their mission to the Land of Tea (*ep 106 in Naruto). I think that's the closest thing Naruto has to killing somebody on his own without any variables.

Answer (score 2):

Naruto killed white zetsus, you can see it here,

[Naruto Vs White Zetsu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFp9pgE9Osk)

While if you consider them "persons" or not, it's debatable. This wikia describes them as race: humans

[[White Zetsu](https://xianb.fandom.com/wiki/White_Zetsu)]

This another wikia entry describe white zetsu as "mutated human",

[Zetsu](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Zetsu)

And this other wikia entry,

[White Zetsu Army](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/White_Zetsu_Army)

describes the white zetsu army as "originally humans who fell victim to Kaguya's Infinite Tsukuyomi and were bound by the roots of the God Tree." , later as "No longer humans" and finally as "Because of their modifications, their DNA is very similar to Hashirama"(who was human)

So to the topic question "Has Naruto ever killed anyone?", the answer is yes, and to the content of the topic question which is different "Naruto has been in an awful lot of fights but I can't recall if he ever actually killed another person." the answer is kind of.

[image]

Comment: Naruto's chakra caused them to turn into tree. Would it be considered killing? See comments below the first answer. I would consider it immobilisation rather than dead. Besides they are turning into trees which is not something dead (converting to one lifeform to another).

Comment: I have asked: [When zetsu clones gets converted into trees, do they die?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/64093/when-zetsu-clones-gets-converted-into-trees-do-they-die)

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami answered there, also he killed with a kunai and other ways and that one didnt turn into a tree

Answer (score 1):

Hiruko from will of fire was fatally wounded by Naruto's rasenshiruken

Not 100% sure if true but I watched th end part of the movie and it seems that he died from said blow

Comment: Can you provide proof of this?

Answer (score 1):

Naruto killed at least 2 guys

https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Aoi_Rokush%C5%8D

> Naruto then fought Aoi, and eventually defeated him with the Rasengan;
> by aiming at the crack on the sword, Naruto was able to break it. Once
> the Rasengan hit Aoi, it sent him flying off the cliff where he fell
> headfirst into the water.[4] Seeing as he said that a fall from that
> height was fatal, Aoi died from the fall.

https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Y%C5%ABra

> Ultimately, Yūra was defeated and killed by Naruto's Big Ball
> Rasengan. His corpse was later devoured by Zetsu.

https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/F%C5%ABka

> As they battled, Naruto noticed that Fūka was constantly switching
> bodies to perform different elemental techniques, and that her hair
> was of more importance to her than her body. In turn, he continuously
> attacked her hair (which destroyed her bodies) and left her in her
> purest state — a soul. As the battle came to a close, Naruto charged
> at her with a Rasengan in hand, and she at him with her hair. The
> former managed to land his attack first, resulting in her quick demise
> from a blow to the head

I have also read that Naruto killed many other white zetsu. However, I haven't watched that part.

So yea, the 2 guys and white Zetsu.

Naruto himself has never shown compunction on killing at all. Like all Ninja, he fights to kill.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one more guy that is killed by Naruto - "[Shura](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Shura)":

> Shura kidnaps Akio. Naruto and the others go to Shinobazu's base to free him. Shura beats Akio demanding to know where Gantetsu hid the stolen treasure. Todoroki charges in and Gantetsu gets captured. The building burns and Todoroki panics, but overcomes his fears to help Gantetsu and his brother escape. Naruto fights Shura and defeats him with Rasengan sending him plummeting to his death in the forests below.

Answer (score -3):

I remember he killed Fuuka in one of the filler episodes by cutting her hair.

Comment: Welcome to the community. We hope you contribute well to this community. About your answer, it would be better if you could provide and better and more detailed answer with some kind of a proper reference. A one line answer probably wouldn't cut it for most of the questions around here. So try improving upon this answer for a start.