# Do zetsu clones die when they converts into trees?

Tags: naruto

User @Pablo answered [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12839/has-naruto-ever-killed-anyone/64091#64091) that concludes that Naruto has killed white Zetsu clones. Due to Naruto's chakra, the Zetsu clones turn into trees. The reason is written in this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/When-a-White-Zetsu-clone-dies-why-does-a-tree-emerge-from-him) and [wiki:](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/White_Zetsu_Army)

> Due to their genetic structure, direct contact with somebody that exudes a powerful life force, such as Naruto in Nine-Tails Chakra Mode, causes them to turn into trees.

Naruto didn't have a killing intent(?) but due to Naruto's chakra that exudes life-force, they converts into trees (which is a somewhat of a life-form). I have commented under his answer:

> Naruto's chakra caused them to turn into tree. Would it be considered killing? See comments below the first answer*. I would consider it immobilisation rather than dead. Besides they are turning into trees which is not something dead (converting to one lifeform to another)

*Comments below first answer:

> He killed multiple white zetsus though ;) – Sahan De Silva Mar 24 '17 at 9:33
>
> @SahanDeSilva he made them into tree, so not really dead – Ankit Sharma Feb 17 '19 at 6:46

**Question**: Does Zetsu clones die when it gets converted into trees? Is it more of a immobilization rather than dying?

Comment: If Quora is a valid source of evidence (personally I think it isnt, that's why I avoided to post this link in the former question), this quora topic states they've been killed by Naruto, both by the asker and the replier https://www.quora.com/When-a-White-Zetsu-clone-dies-why-does-a-tree-emerge-from-him

Comment: BTW, I dont agree with Naruto not having a killing intent. That scene in the youtube link I posted, it isnt the only time Naruto killed zetsus. There is at least another time where he killed an infiltrated one who was camouflaged/disguised as a ninja, in a team of ninjas he met when running, and he clearly had the intention of killing the infiltrated one. I think it's more debatable to state if he killed a "person". By their descriptions of mutated humans, I think they could be considered "half humans" or "half persons"

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm not going to use an anime source for replying this, but a medical/legal source,

> Brain death means the person has died.

[Brain death](https://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/health/conditionsandtreatments/brain-death)

So, since when they turn into trees, they no longer have brains, I think it's safe to state that they die, as least as humans